# Store and forward to eventHub a lot of data

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, azure-eventhub

We're developing an InternetOfThings application. Actually we get the data from the device and send to EventHub on Azure.
We could have a lot of connection problems on the field, sometimes offline periods that can even last for days.
Is there a library to store and forward our messages and forward to eventhub when possible? We hear about rabbitmq but here the volume of data is huge (near 3/4 gb per day). Is it capable to manage that volumes? Have someone expirience in a similar scenario?

Comment: How many messages per second are you expecting?

Comment: Actually 30-40 msg/sec. In a near future they could become 500-600 msg/sec (I still have to test if it is possible).

Comment: A RabbitMQ broker should easily accommodate 10000 msg/sec. Of course depending on message properties, server config and so on, this number might vary.

Comment: ok but also If store and forward setting is enabled? if the connection goes down for a long time, like 1 day what appends when it returns?

Comment: Please ask these kind of follow up questions on our mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users